# SSL Caching prevends https requests

Tags: https, wordpress

I use the W3 Total Cache Plugin for Wordpress.

If I enabled "Cache SSL (https) requests" in W3 Total Cache and testing my site at https://securityheaders.io for security reports, then I get only one time a positive response.

Anyone know I can fix that?

The problem is when I disabled the SSL Caching the 304 header (Last-Modified) don´t works anymore.

If I clear the cache then it works again and the response is positive. But i can´t clear the cache every time after an request for every user.

Or I have a wrong thought ?

Comment: Could you elaborate on how the result is negative the second time?

Comment: CSP, X-Frame Options, X-Content Options, XXS, Referrer Policy. But on my page the browser still declares the site as safe.

Comment: @rgcapo Where is the cache being stored? On your server disk, memory, or on a third party CDN like CloudFlare? Also can you post the response headers you get from uncached and cached pages? (Look in Dev Tools, Network tab, click the first thing listed.)

Comment: Thanks for answer! Cache stored on server disk. In Chrome Dev Tool, Network Tab only are timecounts, nothing else. I disabled now the whole PageCache and enabled only Browser Caching and it works fine. But isn´t it possible to cache with PageCache and SSL?